# Convert multi KML and KMZ into shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, convert, kml, kmz, error-000814

I try to convert with arcpy (python 2.7.8) 50 KML and KMZ files, that i downloaded from google earth into shapefiles. All files located in many sub-Folders. All Sub Folders are located in one large directory. When i run this code:

```
import arcpy,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"C:\Project\gis\layers"
pattern = '*.km*'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion( r"C:\Project\gis\layers" ,r'C:\Project\gis')
```

i get an error:

```
C:\Project\gis\layers\ESD.kml
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000814: Invalid file type
Failed to execute (KMLToLayer).
```

I red:

[Python Script to convert a mass of KMLs to a single fGDB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55259/python-script-to-convert-a-mass-of-kmls-to-a-single-fgdb)

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/KML_To_Layer/00120000004w000000/ but didn't understand my code mistake

Answer (score 2):

I think you are seeing that particular error message from this line of your code:

```
arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion( r"C:\Project\gis\layers" ,r'C:\Project\gis')
```

[arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000004w000000) expects a file as its first parameter (KML or KMZ) but you are giving it a folder name.

You could try concatenating the contents of your `filename` variable, with the appropriate delimiter, onto it.