# Copy feature class with the same name from different gdbs/datasets into one gdb

Tags: python, arcpy, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I have 200 gdbs, with the same structure: one dataset with five features (see below)

[image]

I need to copy the feature named "GSUP_USO_Vegetacao" from all 200 gdbs to another gdb, also, name the output features with "GSUP_USO_Vegetacao_name of gdb" ("GSUP_USO_Vegetacao_A1", example above)
I tried using arcpy fuctions but I'm stuck in this scirpt:

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = #geodatabase path
outgdb = #new geodatabase path named "all.gdb"
search = "GSUP_USO_Vegetacao"
fc = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")

for gdb, datasets, features in arcpy.da.Walk(os.environ.workspace):
     for dataset in datasets:
         for feature in fc:
     arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(feature,os.path.join(outgdb,"GSUP_USO_Vegetacao"+gdb)
```

What do I need to do with this script?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the geodatabases are within the same folder, you just need to iterate through the folder of geodatabases, then save a copy of the feature class with the new name. Just change the second and third variables to match your conditions. It's not necessary to iterate through the datasets when you set the workspace because table names have to be unique throughout a geodatabase.

Edit: This script doesn't create the output gdb, so one must create a new gdb first

```
import os
import arcpy

input_fc_name = 'GSUP_USO_Vegetacao'
folder_of_gdbs = r'C:\Path\To\FOLDER\Containing\GDBS'
output_gdb_path = r'C:\Path\To\Output.gdb'

# assumes all gdbs are in folder_of_gdbs
input_gdbs = [g for g in os.listdir(folder_of_gdbs) if g.upper().endswith('.GDB')]

for gdb in input_gdbs:
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(folder_of_gdbs, gdb)  # set workspace
    out_fc_name = input_fc_name + '_' + os.path.splitext(gdb)[0]  # gets rid of extension (e.g ".gdb")
    out_fc_path = os.path.join(output_gdb_path, out_fc_name)
    arcpy.AddMessage(out_fc_name)
    arcpy.management.Copy(input_fc_name, out_fc_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at solving your problem by making a few modifications to the code in [this other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/407509/123828).

```py
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os
import pathlib

def export_layers_to_single_gdb(input_gdb_folder, 
                                target_dataset_name,
                                target_layer_name, 
                                output_gdb, 
                                overwrite_output_gdb,):
    '''
    Function that reads an input folder with multiple GDB files and copies one 
    specific layer from each GDB to the output GDB. 
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    input_gdb_folder : str
        The input folder that contains all the GDBs that will be looked into
    target_dataset_name : str
        The name of the dataset to serch for the target layer. If the target 
        layer is not contained in a dataset, just use either an empty string or 
        None for this value: '' or None
    target_layer_name : str
        The name of the layer to be copied from all input GDBs to the 
        consolidated output GDB 
    output_gdb : str
        Path for the consolidated output GeoDataBase (.gdb) file. 
    overwrite_output_gdb : boolean
        Flag that indicates whether or not the consolidated output GDB file 
        should be overwritten in this process in case a file with the same name 
        already exists on disk.
    
    Returns
    -------
    None.
    
    Outputs
    -------
    This function copies the target layer from several input into creates a master GDB file 
    
    '''
    # Fishing out the output folder and the GDB filename
    output_gdb_path = pathlib.Path(output_gdb)
    output_folder = str(output_gdb_path.parent)
    master_gdb = output_gdb_path.stem + output_gdb_path.suffix
    
    # Creating master consolidated output GDB. This will store the finalized 
    # combined layers.
    master_gdb_fullpath = os.path.join(output_folder, master_gdb)
    if ((os.path.exists(master_gdb_fullpath)) and (overwrite_output_gdb)):
        arcpy.Delete_management(master_gdb_fullpath)
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_folder, master_gdb)
        
    # Get list of all GDBs in the input folder
    list_of_input_gdbs = [f for f in os.listdir(input_gdb_folder) 
                          if (f[-4:].lower()=='.gdb')]
    
    # Looping over every input GDB file
    for i,input_gdb in enumerate(list_of_input_gdbs):
        # Getting the full path of the input GDB
        input_gdb_fullpath = os.path.join(input_gdb_folder, input_gdb)

        arcpy.env.workspace = input_gdb_fullpath
        
        # Copying the Featureclass from the input GDB to the Master GDB
        print(f"COPYING: {target_layer_name} FROM: {input_gdb}")
        if (target_dataset_name is None) or (target_dataset_name == ''):
            fcCopy = os.path.join(input_gdb_fullpath, 
                                  target_layer_name)
        else:
            fcCopy = os.path.join(input_gdb_fullpath, 
                                  target_dataset_name, 
                                  target_layer_name)
        
        new_layer_name = target_layer_name + '_' + input_gdb
        
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
            fcCopy, master_gdb_fullpath, new_layer_name)
```

Btw, I wasn't able to test it myself, so please let me know if it crashed on some step.